# How do I connect Apache to my running Ruby on Rails instance using passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, apache, passenger

I’m using Apache 2.4 and Rails 5 on Mac Sierra. I did

```
brew install passenger
```

and then I created this file

```
localhost:apache2 davea$ cat /etc/apache2/other/passenger.conf
LoadModule passenger_module  /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
```

But after restarting Apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

and then starting my Rails server (which runs on port 3000), I visit the local url on my machine

```
https://mylocalurl.com/
```

and I’m still seeing my Apache page, not my Rails page. What else am I missing that would connect Apache to Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a virtualhost in apache and then Passenger will start your rails app for you (you don't start your rails server when using apache integration).

At a minimum you need to point the apache virtualhost's document root to the public directory in your rails app.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourserver.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/myapp/public

    <Directory /path/to/myapp/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Further reading:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/intro.html
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/

Comment: Hi, I put what you have above in my "httpd.conf" file but upon restarting Apache, I get teh error (from the logs), "Cannot serve directory /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/sims/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive".

Comment: `/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/sims/` should be `/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/sims/public`